# {controller} placeholder doesn't work when generating TypeScript client with NSwag

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, openapi, auto-generate, nswag

I want to generate a TypeScript client from an OpenApi specification. I'm using NSwagStudio to create the config file. I leave the default `{controller}Client` value, but the placeholder has no effect, as the class name is generated as just `Client`.

What could be the problem?

```
"codeGenerators": {
   "openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
     "className": "{controller}Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
...
```

```
[ApiController]
public class WorkoutsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWorkoutService _workoutService;

    public WorkoutsController(IWorkoutService workoutService)
    {
        _workoutService = workoutService;
    }

    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(WorkoutResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [HttpGet(ApiEndpoints.Workouts.Get)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] Guid id, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var workout = await _workoutService.GetByIdAsync(id, token);
        if (workout is null)
            return NotFound();

        var workoutResponse = workout.ToWorkoutResponse();
        return Ok(workoutResponse);
    }
...
```

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
        "title": "fitflow.RestApi",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/workouts/{id}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Workouts"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "in": "path",
                        "required": true,
                        "style": "simple",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "uuid"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "content": {
                            "text/plain": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WorkoutResponse"
                                }
                            },
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WorkoutResponse"
                                }
                            },
                            "text/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WorkoutResponse"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "404": {
                        "description": "Not Found",
                        "content": {
                            "text/plain": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
                                }
                            },
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
                                }
                            },
                            "text/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/api/workouts": {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `NSwag.AspNetCore` package installed from NuGet. Otherwise if you have the default `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` installed, it will use that, which would be undesirable in this case and would cause the issue you are experiencing.

In addition, ensure you have the following in your `Program.cs`. This is required for OpenAPI 3.0 generation through NSwag:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument();
```

And these are the NSwag extensions for serving Swagger docs:

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseOpenApi();     // use in place of app.UseSwagger()
app.UseSwaggerUi3();  // use in place of app.UseSwaggerUI()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found something related with that issue.

This state is related with shape of `operationId` attribute in json file generated by Swagger.

For sure at 100% your `operationId` in json doesn't have the controller name in value (as prefix).

To generate separate class names for each of API controllers the `operationId` should does look like that: `controller_action`.
With option `operationGenerationMode` set to `MultipleClientsFromOperationId` in `.nswag` config file everything should be generated as expected.

In my Angular project I have three API controllers for now and only for one of them the `operationId` is generating with expected mask `controller_action`.

For some reasons for rest of them, the `operationId` contains only the action name.

1. If you have got the situation that for all of api controllers the `operationId` attributes are generating in wrong way (wrong for that scenario, only with action name) then the best idea will be set `operationGenerationMode` option in `.nswag` config file to value `MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationId`.

   It will use the tag attribute to combine proper class name in api.service.ts generated file.
2. In my scenario, where for some controllers `operationId`'s are generated well but for some not, probably I have to implement own class to handle way of generating this `operationId`, so:

   ```
   using System;
   using NSwag.Generation.Processors;
   using NSwag.Generation.Processors.Contexts;

   public class OperationIdProcessor : IOperationProcessor
   {
        public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
        {
            var controllerName = context.ControllerType.Name.Replace("Controller", "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var actionName = context.MethodInfo.Name;

            var operationId = $"{controllerName}_{actionName}";
            context.OperationDescription.Operation.OperationId = operationId;

            return true;
        }
   }
   ```

   and in my `Program.cs` file where I have got a services configuration, I need to add:

   ```
   services.AddOpenApiDocument(configure =>
   {
       configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationIdProcessor());
   });
   ```

Of course the perfect solution will be just find the reason why this `operationId` is generating in different ways and unify this process but unfortunately I spend on it a few days and didn't find anything special.

So I started thing about workarounds (like with additional class to handle process of creating `operationId`) and decided to share my investigation results.

Maybe my small pieces of solution will be helpful to find this one, perfect, solution or will be just the solution for someone.